# Serving assets as separate files in Heroku - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am working on a Rails 3 app and I need to get my js files in separate files on Heroku for debugging. On the local host when I run in development ENV it works fine.
On Heroku it serves the files separately and at the same time serves application.js with all the code in it, so the code is loaded twice which creates a lot of problems.

Things I tried:

1) Setting RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV to 'development' in Heroku

2) Setting:

```
# Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
```

in both production.rb and development.rb

3) copying the entire content of development.rb to production.rb

4) using

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", debug: true %>
```

Nothing helps, I still get application.js with all the code and all the separate files at the same time.

You kind help will be very appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off rails asset pipeline by setting `config.assets.enabled = false` in `config/application.rb`